# I need to click the button twice to make the calculation

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a method that calculates a charge but you need to click the button twice for it to calculate

1. This is the method that fetches the data in the database and calculates

   ```
   public Float findTarifaBandeira1() {
       try {
           //SQL
       } catch (NoResultException ne) {
           System.out.print("Tarifa não encontrada"); // Colocar messagesfaces
       }

       tarifaBand1 = (bandeira.getValorInicial()  + ( bandeira.getTarifaCorrida().getValorKm() * km));
       BigDecimal vt = new BigDecimal(tarifaBand1).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
       tarifaBand1 = vt.floatValue();
       return tarifaBand1;
   }
   ```
2. This method fires the click of the button calls other methods and the method above
   I have a method that calculates a charge but you need to click the button twice for it to calculate

   ```
   public void consultarBandeira() throws ParseException {
       getData();
       getHora();
       convertDistance();
       findTarifaBandeira1();
       findTarifaBandeira2();
       findTarifaVolumesDeMao ();
       findTarifaVolumesNormais ();
       findTarifaVolumesGrandes();
   }
   ```
3. In my JSF page I use a remote command to call the above method

   ```
   <p:commandButton value="#{msg['btn-search']}"
                    styleClass="btn btn-primary" onclick="findRoute()"/>

   <p:remoteCommand actionListener="#{searchBean.consultarBandeira()}"
                    id="consultaValor" name="consultaValor"
                    update="bandeira1, bandeira2, nomeVPequenos,
                            descricaoVPequenos, valorVpequenos, nomeVNormais,
                            descricaoVNormais, valorVNormais, nomeVGrandes,
                            descricaoVGrandes, valorVGrandes"/>
   ```

   `findRoute()` is a function that calls the JavaScript `consultaValor` component that triggers the method in my `searchBean`.

   ```
   function findRoute(){
       event.preventDefault();

       var addressOrigin = origin;
       var addressDestination = document.getElementById("addr").value + 
                                  document.getElementById("city").value;

       var request = {
           origin: addressOrigin,
           destination: addressDestination,
           travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
           unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.metric 
       };

       directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
               directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
               directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("route"));
               var route = response.routes[0];
               for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++){
                   routeSegment = i + 1;
                   distance = route.legs[i].distance.value;
               }
               document.getElementById("distance").value = distance;
           }
       }); 
       consultaValor();
   }
   ```

Comment: Provide the relevant info to replicate the problem. This is: the view (JSP/Facelets) code, the managed bean and its configuration and how you're invoking the method.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info for more hints.

Comment: Your design looks strange. Why do you need a javascript call to findRoute() that then call the remote command? Why don't you call directly using the p:commandButton actionListener?

Comment: Because if I call the actionListener of p: cinnabdButton and onClick javascript findRoute () does not work.

Comment: I meant actionListener="#{searchBean.consultarBandeira()}" in the commandButton... and not use remoteCommand

Comment: Yes, I tried this: 
<P: commandButton  value= "# {msg ['btn-search']}" 
                 styleClass = "btn btn-primary" actionListener="#{searchBean.consultarBandeira()}"  onclick = " findRoute () " />  and does not work.

Comment: We need to see more code to help.  What does your findRoute() function do?

Comment: My fiindRoute () function makes a route using Gmaps and end calls my p: remote command, updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the commandButton, it does a postback to the server twice:  once for the remoteCommand and once for the button itself.  This is most likely the cause of your problem.

Since you're essentially using the button for client-side action only, instruct your commandButton to not postback via onclick.

Also, since you're setting form data in the findRoute() javascript method, you'll need to make sure it is processed on the backend.  The default value of process for remoteCommand is @this.

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msg['btn-search']}"
             styleClass="btn btn-primary" onclick="findRoute(); return false"/>
<p:remoteCommand actionListener="#{searchBean.consultarBandeira()}"
             id="consultaValor" name="consultaValor"
             process="@form"
             update="bandeira1, bandeira2, nomeVPequenos,
                     descricaoVPequenos, valorVpequenos, nomeVNormais,
                     descricaoVNormais, valorVNormais, nomeVGrandes,
                     descricaoVGrandes, valorVGrandes"/>
```

But if it were me, I'd simplify this by combining the logic into the commandbutton itself:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msg['btn-search']}"
             styleClass="btn btn-primary" onstart="findRoute()"
             action="#{searchBean.consultarBandeira()}"
             process="@form"
             update="bandeira1, bandeira2, nomeVPequenos,
                     descricaoVPequenos, valorVpequenos, nomeVNormais,
                     descricaoVNormais, valorVNormais, nomeVGrandes,
                     descricaoVGrandes, valorVGrandes" />
```

Comment: His explanation actually makes sense, did it in my code but I still need double-click the button to the calculation be done completely. I do not know how to solve this problem anyone have another suggestion?

Comment: Another option would be to use a `<p:button/>` instead of a `<p:commandButton/>`

Comment: Updated answer to include new suggestion.